# Multiple autolayout constraints with same variable value

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Is there a way to set the constant of multiple constraints, from code(or directly in interface builder), without having to create a IBOutlet for each constraint?

[image: screenshot from xcode - interface builder]

Comment: An outlet collection ?

Comment: This way I would have to iterate through every constraint in the collection. Is there a way a way to do in interface builder directly? having the '18' in the the "constant" field say "some random variable" ?
But maybe outlet collection is the best way to go..

Comment: I don't think you can bind like that in IB / iOS

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
for constraint in view.constraints {
    // Identify the constraint using a combination of the following:
    // constraint.identifier ==
    // constraint.firstAttribute ==
    // constraint.firstItem ==
    // constraint.secondAttribute ==
    // constraint.secondItem ==
    // constraint.multiplier ==
    // constraint.constant ==
    if constraint-is-correctly-identified {
        constraint.constant = 42
    }
}
```